# ASP.NET MVC Problem accessing data from third table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem to show data from table "Building_Address" in view of "Lease_Status" - it shows no records - only column names as on the pic

[image]

The diagram of tables and relations is:

[image]

the code of cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<test_ent_frame.Models.Lease_Status>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index"; }

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") </p> <table class="table">
    <tr>
      
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Room_Details.number)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Building_Address.City)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) { <tr>
  
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Room_Details.number)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Building_Address.City)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id_Lease }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id_Lease }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id_Lease })
    </td> </tr> }

</table>
```

The code of controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using test_ent_frame.Models;

namespace test_ent_frame.Controllers
{
    public class Lease_StatusController : Controller
    {
        private testEntities db = new testEntities();

        // GET: Lease_Status
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var lease_Status = db.Lease_Status.Include(l => l.Room_Details);
            return View(lease_Status.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Lease_Status/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Lease_Status lease_Status = db.Lease_Status.Find(id);
            if (lease_Status == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(lease_Status);
        }

        // GET: Lease_Status/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.Id_Room = new SelectList(db.Room_Details, "Id_Room", "Id_Room");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Lease_Status/Create
        // Aby zapewnić ochronę przed atakami polegającymi na przesyłaniu dodatkowych danych, włącz określone właściwości, z którymi chcesz utworzyć powiązania.
        // Aby uzyskać więcej szczegółów, zobacz https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id_Lease,Id_Room")] Lease_Status lease_Status)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Lease_Status.Add(lease_Status);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.Id_Room = new SelectList(db.Room_Details, "Id_Room", "Id_Room", lease_Status.Id_Room);
            return View(lease_Status);
        }

        // GET: Lease_Status/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Lease_Status lease_Status = db.Lease_Status.Find(id);
            if (lease_Status == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.Id_Room = new SelectList(db.Room_Details, "Id_Room", "Id_Room", lease_Status.Id_Room);
            return View(lease_Status);
        }

        // POST: Lease_Status/Edit/5
        // Aby zapewnić ochronę przed atakami polegającymi na przesyłaniu dodatkowych danych, włącz określone właściwości, z którymi chcesz utworzyć powiązania.
        // Aby uzyskać więcej szczegółów, zobacz https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id_Lease,Id_Room")] Lease_Status lease_Status)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(lease_Status).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.Id_Room = new SelectList(db.Room_Details, "Id_Room", "Id_Room", lease_Status.Id_Room);
            return View(lease_Status);
        }

        // GET: Lease_Status/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Lease_Status lease_Status = db.Lease_Status.Find(id);
            if (lease_Status == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(lease_Status);
        }

        // POST: Lease_Status/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Lease_Status lease_Status = db.Lease_Status.Find(id);
            db.Lease_Status.Remove(lease_Status);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

These are standard scaffolded files in visual studio

How to make it possible to show these records?

Debug:

[image]

Comment: Is the model hydrated in Controller before you return the view?

Comment: I really dont know what it means - I just started to learn. I added the code of controller in my post

Comment: If you set a debugger on `return View(lease_Status.ToList());` is there data in `lease_Status` object and linked objects?

Comment: I tried to do what you said and added the screen on the end of my post. I don't know if I set debugger correctly as you said